# Android Gradle adding external library and nested external libraries to a project

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How do i add an external library and nested external libraries to an android project?

---

**My project structure (Not allowed to change)**

- Apps/

  - App1/

    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
  - libraries/

    - library1/

      - build.grade
      - settings.gradle
    - library2/

      - build.grade
      - settings.gradle
    - library3/

      - build.grade
      - settings.gradle
    - library4/

      - build.grade
      - settings.gradle

---

### App1

**App1/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':..:libraries:library1')
    compile project(':..:libraries:library2')
    compile project(':..:libraries:library3')
    compile project(':..:libraries:library4')
}

android {
    ...
}
```

App1 does not directly depend on `library3` or `library4`, however, it will complain if i don't include them in the dependencies in the `build.gradle` file and the `settings.gradle` file. So, i have them included just to stop it from complaining.

**App1/settings.gradle**

```
include ':'
include '..:libraries:library1'
include '..:libraries:library2'
include '..:libraries:library3'
include '..:libraries:library4'
```

---

### library1

**library1/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':..:library3')
    compile project(':..:library4')
}

android {
    ...
}
```

**library1/settings.gradle**

```
include ':'
include '..:library3'
include '..:library4'
```

---

### library2..4

**library2..4/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    ...
}
```

**library2..4/settings.gradle**

```
include ':'
```

---

When trying to `gradlew clean build` on `App1` i get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/user/projects/branches/branch1/Apps/libraries/library1/build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':..:library:library1'.
> Project with path ':..:library3' could not be found in project ':..:library:library1'.
```

Line 15 is `compile project(':..:library3')` in the `library1/build.gradle` file.

How do i add an external library and nested external libraries to an android project?

Comment: I'm curious if anyone familiar with the Settings DSL / Groovy could come up with a snippet that parses nested settings.gradles. This is particularly helpful for submodules. Currently, adding a project *anywhere* causes the build to break all the way up the chain.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your top level settings.gradle (App1/settings.gradle) file do something like this for each library

```
include ':library1'   
include ':library2'   
include ':library3'   
include ':library4'   

project(':library1').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../libraries/library1')
project(':library2').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../libraries/library2')
project(':library3').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../libraries/library3')
project(':library4').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../libraries/library4')
```

Remove the other settings.gradle files, you don't need them

then in each build script you only need to use

```
compile project (':library1')
compile project (':library2')
etc....
```

as stated above just use a single settings.gradle file in the root project (App1).

Then from your App1 folder run `gradlew clean :library1:build` to validate that library1 is building correctly.

As for the issue about App1 complaining about missing libraries 3 & 4, are you sure you have no code in the app directly referencing these libraries, either that or the libraries are not being found when compiling library1. Build each library individually to validate they all build ok.

Comment: I did build each individually and they all built fine. Still having trouble getting your suggestion to work. I keep getting the error that `Evaluation project 'library2' using empty build file.`

Comment: can you confirm the paths are correct for the project definition. Also not sure if there is a missing ':' in from of 'library2'?

Comment: Yeah, they are correct. Checked and re-checked several times. Also did copy and pasting to make sure. However, i am actually trying a different method to solve my problem and i am having a lot of success with it so far. I will post my results as soon as i have confirmed it working completely.

Comment: I had to use braces in order to get this to work, i.e. `compile project (':library1')` rather than `compile project ':library1'`

Comment: Updated the answer, thanks @tmalseed for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

One question. 
Do you need this dependency tree?

```
--- App
   |--- Library 2
   |--- Library 1
       |--- Library 3
       |--- Library 4
```

If yes, your App does not need import the libraries 3 and 4. These dependencies are available over the Library 1.

About settings.gradle files. Why one in each module? This file is only used in the root project (like Eclipse workspace) to reference your modules (App,  Library 1, Library 2,  etc...)

This help you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this for relative paths:

```
include '..:ambilWarna'
include '..:excel'
include '..:pdfjet'
include '..:commons'
include '..:volley'


include  ':odb2'
include  ':azure'

include ':carBase'
include ':fuelTrackerLib'
include ':comsourcecastlelogbook'
```