# Android Studio: using Android Modules without duplicating code

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I need to implement two applications `AppA` and `AppB` that use the same Android Library `LibC`.

Using Android Studio, my desire is to have three projects: `LibC`, `AppA`, and `AppB`, with `AppA` and `AppB` referencing `LibC`. I cannot find a way to obtain this.

So far I have implemented `AppA`. While writing `AppA` I created a module via

```
File > New Module > Android Library > `LibC`
```

The `LibC` library is now in the `AppA` project and I need to start using it within the `AppB` project.

#### Question 1:

How do I move `LibC` out of project `AppA` and create a project only for `LibC`?

#### Question 2:

How am I supposed to create a new project containing only an Android Library?

If I start a new Android Project it keeps creating a new App.

[The doc here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/create-project.html) says:

> 1) that I need to create a new Application and then a new module within that application (which is what I did while writing `AppA`);
>
> 2) that I can import existing library code into a new project.

However I **do not want to copy the code** of the library into the new project (which is what happens), I want to use the **same** files in order to keep a single code base for the library.

Is this possible? If it is, where can I find some doc about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference without copying a library project on Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494105/how-to-reference-without-copying-a-library-project-on-android-studio)

Answer (score 5):

Since I had this requirement in my own project recently, I may have some suggestions for you.

Basically here are your options:

## 1. Single project with different modules

If AppA and AppB are somehow related (this is something you have to decide), you can go the easy way. You already have AppA and LibC in your project, so you only need to create another App module in Studio for AppB (File > New module > Application module)

You may see interestingly, that your project directory initially has the name **AppA**, and your AppA module is named **app**. That is because Android Studio per default names your project after the name you provided in the wizard, while your first module is always named **app**.

You may rename your containing project from **AppA** to something like **project** (via *right-click on project > Refactor > rename*, and rename the **app** module to **AppA**.

The basic structure will look like this:

```
Studio Project AppA (rename to "project")
|
|\_app (module AppA, rename to "AppA")
| |_ src
|
|\_AppB (module AppB)
| |_ src
|
 \_LibC (module LibC, dependency for AppA and AppB)
  |_ src
```

Advantage of this setting is that it is contained in one Android Studio project, and therefore you get all the Android Studio refactoring magic between your app modules and the library for free.

Imagine you change a method in LibC, it would be reflected in both AppA and AppB.

## 2. Different projects, library symlinked

Basically this reflects your thought of having **two different** project locations for AppA and AppB - without having 2 physical LibC locations. Just take LibC (AppA) and symlink it to the new location (AppB).

Not a beautiful solution but possible (I can only speak for Unix like systems, but should work on Win as well.)

```
Studio Project AppA (location 1 on disk)
|
|\_app
| |_ src
|
 \_LibC (dependency for app)
  |_ src

… 

Studio Project AppB (location 2 on disk)
|
|\_app
| |_ src
|
 \_*LibC (symlinked from AppA project dir)
  |_ src
```

**Beware that inter-project refactoring will fail** in that case, e.g. you open project AppA, make substantial changes in LibC, run AppA. later you open AppB and will get compile time failures, since AppB has not been adapted to use LibC’s new APIs.

## 3. Library as an external dependency artefact

This can be considered **by far the most "professional"** way.
Create your App projects, they don’t have to be in the same project tree like in option 1, and link them against a built artefact of your library LibC (aar or jar).

Ideally, this artefact is versioned and located in a (local) maven repository.
That way you always have a consistent build (since you link against a specific version of your library, regardless of the development state LibC is currently in)

```
Studio Project AppA (location 1 on disk)
|
 \_app
  |_ src
  |_ build.gradle dependency on libc (jar/aar + version XX)

… 

Studio Project AppB (location 2 on disk)
|
|
 \_app
  |_ src
  |_ build.gradle dependency on libc (jar/aar + version YY)


Studio Project LibC (location 3 on disk)
|
 \_LibC (library module from AppA project dir)
  |_ src (in development)
```

As you said, Android Studio somehow forces you to create an app module first, before you can create a library module. I hope this will change anytime in the future, but it is no big deal. Just create you library module afterwards, and get rid of the app module. You can then build your library via gradle and export the artefact (aar or jar) to be used with your project.

In LibC’s build.gradle you may find something like this to deploy it to your local machine’s maven repository:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
group = 'your.groupid.artefactid'
version = '0.2.0'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository url: 'file://' + new File(System.getProperty('user.home'), '.m2/repository').absolutePath
        }
    }
}
```

See http://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/ for reference.

If you run `gradle uploadArchives`, it creates your artefact and pushes it into your local maven repository.

#### [EDIT]

There is another possibile solution, similar to option 2. Reference the library from multiple projects via gradle as a File reference, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21021293/1128600

This method also has the drawbacks of option 2 (no multiple API versioning, no inter-app syncing when refactoring)

Hope that summary based on personal experience helps you in finding a direction.

I personally would go with either option 1 if Apps are related, or option 3 (Maven)

Comment: After some other attempts I ended up with an implementation that corresponds to your option 1. It is ok for small projects, but clearly it does not scale when the library is shared among 'a lot' of apps or unrelated apps (like in my case: now I have four apps a,b,c,d using the library, but there are only two related couples - a&b, c&d). I would not use the 'symlink' solution. Maven would be ok, but I would rather not introduce its complexity in this development line.

Comment: Actually using Maven (as a local repository as shown in the example) does address all the problems you are talking about + scaling, and is not really complex (< 10 lines of build.gradle). I suggest giving it a try.

Comment: I created a new project from scratch. First and only thing, I did a refactor of the 'app' module, renaming it to 'AppA'. Now I have this error: "Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: AppA. Could you please check? This happened after the upgrade to 1.1.0.

Comment: Maven is ok, but I think it adds a layer of complexity which is absolutely unnecessary fort projects of this size (few apps with a couple of shared libraries).

Comment: I did not see the StackOverflow question you added. However, I tried other solutions reported not to replicate code and they did replicate in my case. Thanks.

Comment: From what I could see, there may be a few hiccups, try those steps:
1. Module names may not be equal to project name. So try to change the project name first, then the module name.
2. When changing module name, make sure the new module name is reflected in settings.gradle as well.
3. When done changing module names, just to be sure, close the project in Studio, delete the generated *.iml files (project and module), the .idea folder and re-import the project via Import Project => select project's build.gradle. Gradle rebuilds .iml files and .idea folder, so don't worry about it.

Comment: I will try. In these first trials I created a project with a reasonable name that I wouldn't need to change: let's say that the new project is called 'project'. Then I renamed 'app' to 'AppA': here the problems start. Cleaning the project does not affect anything.

Comment: Can you tell why you unaccepted the answer? Was anything missing or unclear?

Comment: If you want to work it out and still need help, please be a bit more verbose, else I accept that.

Comment: I am experiencing a lot of strange and absurd errors that I did not have before renaming. The effort to make it work is not worth the time and clearly shows that it's not the best option for sharing the code of a simple module. An alternative solution is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I used a simpler approach.
Let's say you have two things:

1. Your Application Project
2. Your Module. Let's name it MyLib. (You can change your module name from app to MyLib by click on app>Refactor>Rename module).

Now Come to your **application project**, where you need to import this module. Go to Settings.gradle it should look like this

> include ':app'

Now

Step 1: Add relative path of your module here. e.g in my case my project and my module was inside same directory

```
Projects
|
|\_MyApplication/app
|\_MyModule/MyLib
```

Now You need to add MyLib Module in **Settings.gradle** of MyApplication. It should look like this

> include ':Project','../MyModule:MyLib'

We are almost there.

Click "Sync now". Now Click on "MyApplication" go to OpenModuleSettings>Dependencies. Click on + and then 'Module Dependency'.  You will see "MyLib" in option there. Just add it.

Done.

P.S: Android Studio will now show you MyLib Project inside Android studio. It isn't copied, its just showing the attached files. Your code base is at one place only.